# Is it possible design a portable high powered vacuum cleaner from a 12V DC motor?

Tags: airflow, vacuum

I am currently designing a device that can pick up 20 kid's plastic balls from one box and transfer them all into another box. I have decided to use a vacuuming method to vacuum up the balls as my way of picking up the balls. Right now I'm just testing if my idea can just pick up one ball. But anyway, I'm planning to use a 12V DC motor that comes with 18,800 RPM and 4.9kg/cm torque connected to a 120mm diameter centrifugal impeller made of plastic to provide suction. This is all then attached to the top of an L shape pvc pipe of 120mm diameter at the top to fit the impeller and motor, and 80mm diameter at the bottom for the ball fit through. I am also powering this device with 8 1.5V AA batteries and won't be able to use other sources.

At this point I've been doubting if this potential vacuum would even have the sucking power to even vacuum up just one of these 65mm diameter balls. If this device fails which it likely will, would it be that my 12V DC motor isn't powerful enough, or my pvc pipe is too wide or something else. I've read online that it's something to do with a good CFM volume or airflow volume for good suction power, but I'm not too sure what component of the vacuum cleaner would provide this. Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Picture of ball: (https://hiphiphooray.com.sg/product/colourful-air-filled-balls/)

Basic prototype of vacuum: https://ibb.co/q183PCM

Comment: They make vacuums for cars... check this out : https://www.nettoshop.ch/en/Small-household-appliances/Vacuum-cleaners-cleaning/Vacuum-cleaners/Hand-held-vacuum-cleaners/Black%26Decker-Flexi-PD1200A-Vacuum-cleaner/p/IP082830?utm_source=google&utm_medium=productsearch&utm_campaign=googleshopping&gclid=Cj0KCQjws5HlBRDIARIsAOomqA3_vNuEF8yp8mubxXlLolYyrDPNUNsYqFzy6UBqClHeKsOGg70ioYcaAkFwEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: It is not only the CFM but the linear air velocity you need to move more than 1 ball up to some potential energy.   I would imagine if you get more than even 1 ball up, they will jam at the L corner and the concept won't work.  Try again.  THese portable vacuums can barely suck up a ping pong in a smooth pipe.